# How to compose two calls to Regex::replace_all?

Tags: regex, rust

[`Regex::replace_all`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace_all) has the signature `fn (text: &str) -> Cow<str>`. How would two calls to this be written, `f(g(x))`, giving the same signature?

Here's some code I'm trying to write. This has the two calls separated out into two functions, but I couldn't get it working in one function either. Here's my `lib.rs` in a fresh Cargo project:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

/// Plaintext and HTML manipulation.

use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use regex::Regex;
use std::borrow::Cow;

lazy_static! {
    static ref DOUBLE_QUOTED_TEXT: Regex = Regex::new(r#""(?P<content>[^"]+)""#).unwrap();
    static ref SINGLE_QUOTE:       Regex = Regex::new(r"'").unwrap();
}


fn add_typography(text: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    add_double_quotes(&add_single_quotes(text)) // Error! "returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"
}

fn add_double_quotes(text: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    DOUBLE_QUOTED_TEXT.replace_all(text, "“$content”")
}

fn add_single_quotes(text: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    SINGLE_QUOTE.replace_all(text, "’")
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::{add_typography};

    #[test]
    fn converts_to_double_quotes() {
        assert_eq!(add_typography(r#""Hello""#), "“Hello”");
    }

    #[test]
    fn converts_a_single_quote() {
        assert_eq!(add_typography("Today's Menu"), "Today’s Menu");
    }
}
```

Here's the best I could come up with, but this will get ugly fast when composing three or four functions:

```rust
fn add_typography(input: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    match add_single_quotes(input) {
        Cow::Owned(output) => add_double_quotes(&output).into_owned().into(),
        _                  => add_double_quotes(input),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Cow` contains *maybe-owned* data.

We can infer from what the `replace_all` function does that it returns borrowed data only if substitutions did not happen, otherwise it has to return new, owned data.

The problem arises when the inner call makes a substitution but the outer one does not.  In that case, the outer call will simply pass its input through as `Cow::Borrowed`, but it borrows from the `Cow::Owned` value returned by the inner call, whose data now belongs to a `Cow` temporary that is local to `add_typography()`.  The function would therefore return a `Cow::Borrowed`, but would borrow from the temporary, and that's obviously not memory-safe.

Basically, this function will only ever return borrowed data when no substitutions were made by either call.  What we need is a helper that can propagate owned-ness through the call layers whenever the returned `Cow` is itself owned.

We can construct a `.map()` extension method on top of `Cow` that does exactly this:

```
use std::borrow::{Borrow, Cow};

trait CowMapExt<'a, B>
    where B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized
{
    fn map<F>(self, f: F) -> Self
        where F: for <'b> FnOnce(&'b B) -> Cow<'b, B>;
}

impl<'a, B> CowMapExt<'a, B> for Cow<'a, B>
    where B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized
{
    fn map<F>(self, f: F) -> Self
        where F: for <'b> FnOnce(&'b B) -> Cow<'b, B>
    {
        match self {
            Cow::Borrowed(v) => f(v),
            Cow::Owned(v) => Cow::Owned(f(v.borrow()).into_owned()),
        }
    }
}
```

Now your call site can stay nice and clean:

```
fn add_typography(text: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    add_single_quotes(text).map(add_double_quotes)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to have my cake and eat it too: efficiency and uniform API. I found a verbose solution with `match` and added it to my post. A big reason: with a typical dataset, the functions will usually return the input unchanged.

Comment: @Dogweather I might have a solution that is not as verbose as yours but has the same performance properties. Hang tight.

Comment: @Dogweather It's actually just a generic form of your solution, but hiding the mess behind a utility method.

Comment: I think you want that to be called `and_then` or `flat_map`, not `map`.

Comment: @Shepmaster It doesn't much fit any of those names, TBH, if we're taking cues from the standard library (not even `map`) as it doesn't allow the type to be changed. Dogweather can call it whatever they like in their code; the name is the least important part of this answer.

Comment: @Dogweather I think this can possibly be made more efficient still. In the `Cow::Owned` case, if `f()` returns borrowed data, it must be borrowing from `v`. We could check if the borrowed data is equal to `v` and if so just return `Cow::Owned(v)`, avoiding an extra copy. We can't assume they are equal without checking because it could return a borrowed region of the input, for example.

Comment: @cdhowie  Amazing - that's awesome. It should really be in the `Cow` library. Maybe `bind` is an accurate name? The type signature seems to be a special case of it: `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m a) -> m a`

Comment: @Dogweather Yeah, there's probably a few names that would work. Use whatever you think makes the most sense in your code. I think this would make a good addition to the standard library as well, if the `Cow::Owned` case of `f()` returning borrowed content could be suitably optimized.  The equality check has the potential to also be slow, so I'm not exactly sure how that could be handled both correctly and efficiently.

Comment: @cdhowie I updated my answer with a version requiring less keyboarding — a sort of short-circuit, not using `output`, because it's unchanged. I don't fully understand your solution, but maybe this gives you an idea?

Comment: `F: for FnOnce(&B) -> Cow<'_, B>` is simpler, since HRTB is the default desugaring for `Fn*`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Right, I find I prefer more explicit forms sometimes as it requires less mental work to figure out what's actually going on (for me, anyway).

Comment: @cdhowie That's why I didn't edit, but thought it is important to note that anyway :)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yep yep. Desugaring is a double-edged sword... it makes things easier to write at the cost of there being multiple ways to write the same thing, and that in turn opens the door for differing opinions on which form to use.

Comment: @cdhowie FYI I shared your solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/unv4x9/a_solution_for_composing_functions_that_return/

Comment: You could make this function more of a true map, allowing you to change the type, by changing the function signature to `fn map<R, F>(self, f: F) -> Cow<'b, R> where F: for <'b> FnOnce(&'b R) -> Cow<'b, R>`

Comment: @TheHans255 I think you mean `FnOnce(&'b B)`. Yes, that can be made to work if you spell out a bit more what `R` is: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfbe9f27134b388601b3e4d51439598d